# How can i bind the "UITableViewVellAccessory.CheckMark" using my ViewModel?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I need to bind the bool property in my viewModel to the Table Cell property UITableViewVellAccessory.CheckMark? How can i do that?

Comment: Did you tried anything ? Also your question is not clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way would be to set up a boolean property in your cell and bind to that:

```
    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get { return Accessory == UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark; }
        set { base.Accessory = value ? UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark : UITableViewCellAccessory.None; }
    }
```

Another way would be to set up a `ValueConverter` which converts your ViewModel property to a `UITableViewCellAssessory` value

```
    public class MyValueConverter : MvxBaseValueConverter 
    {
        public override object Convert(object value, Type type, object parmeter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            return ((bool) value) ?  UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark : UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
        }
    }
```

Comment: tried second variant with Converter and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate try to check and give the `UITableViewCellAccessory` as per your condition ....

```
if (//here you check)
    { // item needed - display checkmark
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    { // not needed no checkmark
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
```

Comment: var source = new MvxActionBasedBindableTableViewSource(
    tblLicence,
    UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
    new NSString("BookListView"),
    "{'TitleText':{'Path':'Name'},'DetailText':{'Path':'Address'},'SelectedCommand':{'Path':'ContactClickCommand'}}",
UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark);
this.AddBindings(
ew Dictionary<object, string>()
    {
    { source, "{'ItemsSource':{'Path':'Senders'}}" }
});
   
tblLicence.Source = source;
tblLicence.ReloadData();

This is How i Bind my ViewModel with the View, I want to bind the CheckMark according to my bool property